# Retrieving json values from controller to ajax function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have this ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
        $(".exac").append("<div class='ex' id='eas"+i+"' style='cursor:pointer'><h1 id='h1'></h1></div>");
        }
        $('.ex').click(function ()
        {
            var x=$(this).prop("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/random/random", 
                success: function(msg){    
            alert(msg);  
                             if(msg==01101){
                            //$('.ex').attr('disabled','disabled');
                            $(".ex").off('click');
                            $("#hello").append("<button><a href='reset.jsp'>Reset</a></button>");
                        }
                        else{
                    $('<p>'+msg+'</p>').appendTo("#"+x);
                    $("#"+x).off('click');
                   }
               }
            });
        });
        $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

and this is my controler

```
class RandomController < ApplicationController

def random
@n = 8
    respond_to do |format|
      #format.json { render :json => index }
      format.json{render :json => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode( @n )}
        format.html { redirect_to action: "index" }

    end
end

end
```

I am entering the controller using the ajax option and also I get redirected back to the index page but I am not able to recieve the value of `@n=8` back at the index page.Am I missing some step?

This is the error I get in my console

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my above question
my view

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'random',
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
  data: {user:name},
  success: function(response) {
    var foo = $.parseJSON(response);
    if(foo==1001){
      alert("You can select only once");
    }
    else{
       $('<p>'+foo+'</p>').appendTo("#"+x);
        $("#"+x).off('click');
    }
  }
});
```

In the Controller 
I have to just send the response like this

```
render :text => @r.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ruby and rails. However; console.log(msg) instead of alert(msg) and you will see your data structure and from then you can read the data msg.content.

I hope this helps!